# Yii Appending base Url to href

Tags: yii, hyperlink, href

I have external links on my webpage:

```
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href=<?php echo $r['url'] ;?>>
                                                VISIT STORE
                                               </a>
```

When $r['url'] has `http://` it shows the correct external url but when it has only `www` or just the website name with the domain it appends the web page's url.

```
    Case 1 : url = http://google.com    Works fine
    Case 2:  url = www.google.com      creates a link as: http://localhost/appname/controller/action/www.google.com
```

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. If you found the solution for this, please share with me.

Answer (score 1):

Yii has no any relation to your problem. You don't know difference between absolute and relative URL's.

In your code, you don't use Yii anywhere. Yii has very powerfull URL manager with methods: createUrl, createAbsoluteUrl and other. You don't use this.

You need to understand the difference between absolute and relative URL's and your question gone away. There are more information in [internet](http://kb.iu.edu/data/abwp.html) and in StackOverflow too: [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Comment: The links you have given don't solve my problem. If you answering, please post code.

Comment: Please mind how you speak. I don't have control over the url. It is coming in from an API.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Google', '//www.google.com', array('target'=>'_blank')) ?>
```

Comment: It creates url of the form http : // http // google.com

Comment: I added spaces because SO was converting it into a link

Comment: You can use it in this way:
`echo CHtml::link('Google',( strpos( $r['url'], 'www')===0 )?'//'.$r['url']:$r['url'], array('target'=>'_blank'))`

Answer (score 0):

Hope all your URLs are external. Then check your url for `http:`. If url contains http, then use directly, Otherwise add.

```
function is_valid_url($url)
{
   if(strpos($url, "http://")!==false)
      return $url; // correct
   else return "http://$url";// http not found.
}
```

In your `a` tag

```
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href=<?php echo is_valid_url($r['url']) ;?>>
   VISIT STORE  </a>
```